# subscribePending method is not available in (laravel-newsletter) newer version(5.1)

Tags: php, laravel, newsletter

got to know that `Newsletter::subscribePending()` is not present in current version(5.1) of package. How to avail this method or can anybody recommend the alternative package for it which provide both subscribe as well as subscribePending methods?

Package link : [laravel-newsletter package](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-newsletter)

Thank you.

```
use Newsletter;

Newsletter::subscribe($email, ['FNAME' => $fname, 'LNAME' => $lname]);
```

but there is no method to add user as a subscriber with pending status, which user can confirm to subscribe the news letter. i want to available below method -

```
Newsletter::subscribePending($email, ['FNAME' => $fname, 'LNAME' => $lname]);
```

but `subscribePending` is not available in `v5.1`. how to avail it?

Comment: Are you sure it's been removed? I still see it as a function in the MailChimp driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the code of the package, specifically here [MailChimpDriver](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-newsletter/blob/main/src/Drivers/MailChimpDriver.php) you can see that the only thing that `subscribePending()` does is add `['status' => 'pending']` to the options array. So you can basically just bypass the method if you change your code to

```
Newsletter::subscribe($email, [
   'FNAME' => $fname, 
   'LNAME' => $lname, 
   'status' => 'pending'
]);
```

Comment: Thank you @dz0nika. it worked. made slight changes on it-
Newsletter::subscribe($email, [
   'FNAME' => $fname, 
   'LNAME' => $lname
], '', ['status' => 'pending']);